# Monitoring django rest framework api on production server

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, analytics, linode

I have an API created using django rest framework in a [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) server. Now, I want to check the number and the response code of each request, I want to get stats for my api. How can I do it? thankyou so much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[DRF Tracking](http://drf-tracking.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is utilities to track requests to DRF API views, it may be good fit for you:

install:   `pip install drf-tracking`

apply migrations: `python manage.py migrate`

add the following to you API views:

```
 from rest_framework import generics
 from rest_framework_tracking.mixins import LoggingMixin

 class LoggingView(LoggingMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response('with logging')
```

There is also an other alternative [Django Analytics](https://github.com/jcassee/django-analytical) if you want to have more than choice.

Comment: Hi, thanks you but, I'm using mongodb then, can I get trouble with migrations?

Comment: In this case I recommend to use [Django-norel](http://django-nonrel.org/) a django support on non-relational databases.

Answer (score 5):

So the simplest way to get started is to check your webserver's access logs.  That should give you the number of requests in and responses out, including status code.  If you want more feature-full statistics as well as monitoring and alerting, you may want to look into something like NewRelic.

Comment: Think this aproach with combined with splunk.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could use **[drf-tracking](http://drf-tracking.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)**